# Command(s) completed successfully but... the tables are not created

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I backed up my database table's and entire schema into .sql script using Visual Studio's [Database Publishing Wizard](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/12/29/tip-use-the-database-publishing-wizard-to-script-your-table-data.aspx).

I then tried to re-create those tables on another PC, not before re-creating the database itself, with the same exact name and everything (using a script that I created via SSMS's `Script Database as)`.

I then open that tables .sql file using SSMS and execute it.

SSMS reports:

> Command(s) completed successfully

But examining Object Explorer reveals that **no tables were created**.

Why is this happening?

What have I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check whether you have selected database. Most of the times we execute query in Master db by mistake.

-- Mark as answered if this answer really answered your question

Comment: You are the master! That was exactly the problem. I just checked and those tables were created in the `master` System Databases. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I've just been having the **exact same problem symptoms** also using Visual Studio's Database Publishing Wizard, - but with a slightly different cause / fix.

Even though SQL Server Management Studio says it is connected to the correct database (in the drop down in the ribbon, and in the status bar of the window), it wasn't actually connected to anything.

To identify and fix either:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName
```

If you get

```
master
```

(or any other unexpected database name) as the result, then you are connected to the wrong database and should select the correct DB from the dropdown.  This was the cause of your problem.

If you get

```
Command(s) completed successfully
```

then somehow you aren't connected at all - this happened to me.

To fix, click the "change connection" button to disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: yes this was the issue for me.  My SSMS (v17.4) query window in command mode showed every sign of being connected, but when i executed any command it just said command completed successfully.  I changed connection back to what it already looked like it was connected to, and it started working properly.  Nice one!

Comment: this worked, good find

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are running "Execute" or jut Parsing the code. It was a late night, I was tired, and kept running a query to create a table, successfully, but no new table. The next day with a clear mind i noticed that i was not actually running the query, i was parsing it.